# Calculate the average of all NSManagedObjects' attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsexpression

I have an entity with the name `FoodItem`, and it has one attribute, `price` (a double). Ideally, the output of this code would be:

```
Average Price is: 6.00
```

Though I'm not sure how to access the value 6.00. Can anyone assist me? Thank you

Here is my code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FoodItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *o1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[o1 setValue:@(5.00) forKey:@"price"];

NSManagedObject *o2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[o2 setValue:@(7.00) forKey:@"price"];


[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];


[request setSortDescriptors:@[]];

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"price"];
NSExpression *averagePriceExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"average:"
                                                              arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"averagePrice"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:averagePriceExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];


[controller performFetch:nil];

NSLog(@"Average price is: %@", @"");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you use a fetch results controller for this. A `NSFetchedResultsController` is not used for this. Use a simple `NSFetchRequest` for this.

```
// Your previous code here

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Average price is: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"averagePrice"]);
    }
}
```

A simple example of this can be found from Apple doc [Fetching Specific Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html).

Comment: So the only real time I should be using an NSFetchedResultsController is if the data will be displayed in a UITableView?

Comment: Yes. It can also be used with a `UICollectionView` (similar to a table).

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but if I fetch say, an average of a property like before, are the managed objects still fetched and stored in the NSArray *objects as well? How would I go about accessing them?

Comment: @Skyler No, they aren't. You can fecth them in the traditional way.

Comment: Thank you for the response. One last thing, can I fetch multiple properties, such as average, maximum, etc? I suppose I would just add more expressionDescriptions into the array parameter of setPropertiesToFetch? And accessing them would be objects[0], objects[1], etc? Thanks

Comment: @Skyler Sure. `[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];` takes an array!